# How to integrate $e^{-z}$ over the ball $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I can't figure out how to obtain the limits for this triple integral since I can't visualize how $e^{-z}$ varies over a sphere in my head.

Comment: You don't need to think about the behavior of the integrand when finding limits.  The limits are set by the volume you want to integrate over.

Comment: @RossMillikan Why are the limits set by the volume we want to integrate over?

Comment: Even in one dimensional integration that is true.  If I want to integrate $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$, the limits do not depend on $f(x)$, they are just $a$ and $b$.  So you need limits that represent your sphere.  The $e^{-z}$ only comes in when you evaluate the integral, not when you find limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  it is easiest to do the integrals in $x$ and $y$ first.  The integral over them is the area of the sphere perpendicular to the $z$ axis at a particular value of $z$, so is $\pi (1-z^2)$  Then $z$ ranges from $-1$ to $1$, so your integral is $$\int_{-1}^1\pi ( 1-z^2)e^{-z}dz$$

Comment: @RossMillikan The integrals over $x$ and $y$ is basically "looking down" the $z$-axis onto the $xy$-plane, isn't it? Then how can there be a $z$ variable? The area to me looks like $\pi (x^2 + y^2)$.

Comment: The radius of the circle is $\sqrt {1-z^2}$.  At $z=0$ it is a unit circle, at $z=\pm \frac 14$ it is $\frac 12 \sqrt 3$.  Once you integrate over $x,y$ you can't have them in the answer.

Comment: Could you explain how you got that the radius of the circle is $\sqrt{1 - z^2}$?

Comment: From your definition of the sphere, $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1$, write it as $x^2+y^2 \le 1-z^2$

Comment: Ohhh, thank you. Great, I can now visualize the geometry of the limits in my head after this explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Let's write down the limits of the variables:

$z: -\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \to \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$

$y: -\sqrt{1-x^2} \to \sqrt{1-x^2}$

$x: -1 \to 1$.

Set up is:

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} e^{-z} dzdydx$